# How to redefine the second line indent for the author-citation references?

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, indentation, elsarticle

I am using [elsarticle-harv.bst](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle/elsarticle-harv.bst) for author-citation references. However, the indent value for second line is a bit small, see e.g.:
[image]

```
\documentclass[12 pt,a4paper,twoside] {article}
\usepackage{natbib}   
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[lining]{libertine}
\usepackage[ T1 ]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\cite{Tsuji:2008} bla bla ... \\
Bla bla ... \citep[see e.g][]{Shirgaonkar:2009} .

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
\bibliography{reffile} 
\end{document}
```

Reference file `reffile.bib`e.g:

```
@ARTICLE{Tsuji:2008,
  author  = {Tsuji, T. and Yabumoto, K. and Tanaka, T.},
  title   = {Spontaneous structures in three-dimensional bubbling gas-fluidized bed by paralled {DEM-CFD} coupling simulation},
  journal = {  Powder Technology },
  year    = { 2008  },
  volume  = { 184  },
  pages   = {  132-140 },
  number  = { }
  }

@ARTICLE{Shirgaonkar:2009,
  author  = {Shirgaonkar, A. A. and Maclver, M. A. and Patankar, N. A.},
  title   = {A new mathematical formulation and fast algorithm for fully resovled simulation of self-propulsion},
  journal = {Journal of Computional Physics},
  year    = { 2009  },
  volume  = { 228  },
  pages   = {  2366-2390 },
  number  = { }
  }
```

So how to increase the indent?

Comment: You should load the style of the bibliography *before* printing the bibliography.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `natbib` package (I guess it is recommended anyway for `elsarticle-harv`), and then do

```
\setlength{\bibhang}{5em}
```

to increase the indent to `5em` (which is ridiculously large).

Comment: thanks! The default bibhang is 1 em, now 1.5 em is perfect for second-line indent.